# Mac display won't turn on

Tags: hardware, display, power

I have an Apple HD display that has been in our IT depart for a few months now. It was working fine until recently (the past month or two). I can turn it on and it will work for a few days, but then it suddenly will stop working.  If I unplug the monitor, wait for a few days, and then plug it back in, the monitor will work again for a few more days.

I suspect the issue is the 90W power converter, but before I invest the 140 dollars I was wondering: Has anyone else had the same issue? If so, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is new, then I suggest taking it back to Apple for repair, especially if it still under warranty so that you don't have to spend $140 on what is ultimately a guess.

Comment: sorry when I say new I really mean in good shape... I'll change the question to better reflect the prob.